# How add ability add query params for gatsby routes?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

How to generate pages in gatsby that will allow you to add parameters to the routing like  `https://page1?someParam=param` or `https://page1/param`

What I mean? When we navigate to page page1 in gatsby it work's fine, but what if I just want add uniq params for page for google analitics? so for this I want to have ability
add some additional params for the page from where I made redirect, but when I add
for page1 some params like `https://page1?someParam=param` or `https://page1/param`, it updated and show me just `https://page1` instead.

I suppose that it's related to way how I created pages. Here is my code:

```
  createPage({
  path: `${localePrefix}/${slug}`, // so should I change it here in order to work as needed?
  component: PageTemplate,
  context: {
    ...context,
    localizedPaths,
  },
})
```

Can it be fixed with?
matchPath: path: `${localePrefix}/${slug}?*`, 
matchPath: path: `${localePrefix}/${slug}/*`,

Recap:
My question is about why gatsby remove query params from pages?

```
https://some_site/some_page?some_param=323
```

translates into

```
https://some_site/some_page
```

Comment: Params are search queries, they're not handled during build and do not create new pages. You can pass params between pages as props/data with `navigate` or as Ferran has mentioned below, you destruct them with URLSearchParams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https://page1?someParam=param` or `https://page1/param` are not the same. While a query parameter (first case: `?someParam=param`) is an optional value that doesn't change the rendered page (it doesn't point to any specific route hence it's not requesting any file). The second one (`https://page1/param`) is accessing a `/pages/param` route.

Since they are URL parameters, you don't need to change anything in your project, you just need to catch them using JavaScript. They are handled in thee:

```
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window?.location?.search);
```

*Note: you can access directly [`location` prop](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) in Gatsby*

If your project is replacing `https://some_site/some_page?some_param=323` to `https://some_site/some_page` it's because some server-side configuration or a CDN, not because of Gatsby's behavior, like any other React project.